# Three sets of wires for two switches in bathroom

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom

Need a little help please!  I’ve changed every outlet and switch in this house except this one.  When I finally got to it, I got a surprise!  Sadly, I did not take a picture or remember how it was wired before, but I know it was wired incorrectly as one part didn’t work.

What I have > Three sets of wires coming in, two with just black/white/ground and a third with black/white/red/ground.

The B/W/R controls the bathroom light.  One B/W is the bathroom vent fan and the third is tied to a light/switch on the other side of the hallway.  When I reconnected what I thought was correct, when the hallway light is on, the vent fan wont turn on.

I’ve attached a little drawing of what I have coming in.  This is going to be connected to a double switch toggle where the light is controlled on top and the fan on the bottom.  No Idea what to do with the third set of wires and how they tie in.  Just want the single pole switch on the other side to continue to work for the light as before.

The switch they’re being connected to has four posts on it, two on left and two on right.  Ground wires are all taken care of, that part is good to go!

What I know so far.

LIGHT WIRING:  Black and Red make the light go on and off.
FAN WIRING: White from fan, black from light make fan go on and off.
THIRD: Wires didn’t respond to anything, however they were turned off at the switch on the other side.

F[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the black from the light is always hot. So take that hot black and connect it to the black wire for the light in the other room. To that same connection, connect a 6" pigtail and the other end of the pigtail to the common terminal of your double toggle. The common terminal is probably the black screw but verify that with the switch diagram. Take the red from the light and hook it to the top switch terminal, usually a brass screw and hook the black from the fan to the bottom switch terminal, also usually a brass screw. Connect all your white wires together. Good luck and stay safe out there.

Comment: Much Appreciated!  Everything worked except I had to flip the B & W on the fan... it was wired incorrectly but all good now!  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Did you flip the black and white at the fan so the switch box is correct?